# Changing max/min a function will be plotted with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I was hoping someone could shed some light on this issue:
When I plot a function using something like `\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,] (\x,{2 * \x^2 + 4 * \x + 1});` the line of the function does not extend far enough in the window. In other words, how can I expand the domain of the function being plotted?

An example of the plot I am currently creating: 
[image: Plot with functions that needs to be expanded]

Comment: It would really just be helpful to the community if you could provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Something that we can use to reproduce your current problem rather than construction a document from scratch.